# What am I doing wrong? Integration and limits

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I need some help identifying what I'm doing wrong here..

What is the limit of $y(x)$ when $x→∞$ if $y$ is given by:

$$y(x) = 10 + \int_0^x \frac{22(y(t))^2}{1 + t^2}\,dt$$
What i've done:

1) Integrating on both sides(and using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus):

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 0 + \frac{22(y(x))^2}{1 + x^2}$$

2)
$$\frac{-1}{22y} = \arctan x$$
And after moving around and stuff I end up with the answer:  $\quad\dfrac{-1}{11 \pi}.$

What's wrong?

Comment: oops. edited now, thanks! :)

Comment: As David said, it looks like you want 14 and not 22. But another point of concern is that it should be $\frac{-1}{22y} + \frac{1}{22\cdot 10} = \text{atan}(x)$. (Remember that you are integrating from 0 to t and y(0) = 10)

Answer (score 1):

To add my comment above, the answer should be $\frac{-1}{22y} + \frac{1}{22\cdot 10} = \text{atan}(x)$. This reduces to $y(x) = \frac{-1}{22}\cdot (\text{atan}(x) - \frac{1}{220})^{-1}$. On a rigorous level, we know that this holds since $y(x)\geq 10\; \forall\; x$. Now $\text{lim}\; f(x) = \frac{-1}{22}\cdot (\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{1}{220})^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you finish your problem. You are missing the constant of integration

$$ -\frac{1}{y(x)}= \tan^{-1}(x) +c. $$

Now, use the initial condition $y(0)=10$ to find $c$ then you will be able to find the limit.

Comment: One thing though. The initial condition has nothing to do with the integrand, right? If the lower boundary of the integrand was 1 - the initial condition y(0) = 10 would still be the same, right?